# Providing an interface to ArangoDb that allows mongoDb style querying?

Tags: database, mongodb

### Problem

I have an ArangoDb and would like for code written for MongoDb to use it.

### Theory

They are both noSQL databases.

### Question

Before I write my own interface are there any existing tools? Is this approach common? Or am I making my life unnecessarily difficult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jan from ArangoDB here. Can fully understand that you might want to make your life easier with such a portation tool but AFAIK there is no such tool to directly let your mongo queries be "translated" into AQL. And I think you might loose some potentials for optimizations. 
If you haven't seen the tutorial yet, we created one for MongoDB -> ArangoDB https://www.arangodb.com/tutorials/mongodb-to-arangodb-tutorial/

A tool to migrate data can be found here: https://github.com/bbonnin/mongo2arango (was tested with 2.7.x, so not sure if it still works for the version you are using).

Hope I could at least help a bit

Comment: Hi Jan.  Welcome to ServerFault and thanks for answering.  It is ok to include your affiliation, but usually that is better for your profile than the content of a question.